# C char array lose pointer after assingment loop

Tags: arrays, c, char, malloc, c-strings

I'm learning C and I'm so stucked in when allocating memory for a char array in a struct array.

After assigning the value to the char arrays in the first loop, when I try to access the value in a second loop.

Could please anyone help me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this code snippet invokes undefined behavior

```
char string[numDigits];
sprintf(string, "%d", 12345);
```

because the array `string` does not have a space to store the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string built by the call of `sprintf`. You need to declare the array like

```
char string[numDigits+ 1];
```

Secondly this code snippet

```
table[i].str = malloc(sizeof(char) * numDigits);  
table[i].str = string;
```

produces a memory leak because at first a memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `table[i].str` and then the pointer was reassigned.

You need to write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

table[i].str = malloc(sizeof(char) * ( numDigits + 1 ));  
strcpy( table[i].str, string );
```

And at last for loops in the program shall be rewritten like

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ^^^^^^
```